# How long did it take to remove or install an SSME on the Space Shuttle?

Tags: space-shuttle, ssme

Not knowing the steps involved, I am curious how long it took to remove or install an SSME (Space Shuttle Main Engine) in real life.

Answer (score 12):

In the Orbiter Processing Facility (orbiter horizontal) it took, at the end of the program, "less than 4 hours" to install all three engines<sup>1</sup>.

[There's the Orbiter, Go Put a Motor in It](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/behindscenes/engineinstall.html)

Good pictures [here](https://spaceflightnow.com/shuttle/sts135/101210ssme/)

[image]

On the pad, it took longer, 3 or 4 days, at least in 1999. "Shuttle engines have been changed on the launchpad several times in the past and generally it means a three- or four-day delay. "

[source](http://www.cnn.com/TECH/space/9911/03/shuttle.engine.02/index.html)

<sup>1</sup> Wording slightly ambiguous. Could mean a single engine but previous sentence refers to "a set".

Comment: " The center engine was installed on Tuesday, followed by the lower-right engine on Wednesday and the lower-left on Thursday." -> this implies that it took 4 hours per engine, otherwise I can't image why they'd spread it out over three days.  Also, 80 minutes for one SSME seems optimistic: I doubt I connect a dishwasher in 80 minutes.

Comment: Agreed it's ambiguous hence my note.

Comment: I was curious to compare to Raptor mount time, as we watch SpaceX mount, dismount, mount Raptors in the field at this time.

Comment: @geoffc I had actually forgotten that they pulled the engines every flight for most of the shuttle program. So I guess they had plenty of practice.